# Are classic databases needed when we have full-text search engines?

Tags: full-text-search, relational-database

I'm writing a diploma thesis about full-text search engines, and I'm struggling with one fundamental thing.

If we want to have searching on our website, the reason we need dedicated full-text search engines, alongside our classic MySQl/PostgreSQL/Oracle databases, is because databases in general don't have the full-text search capabilities that are needed for quality search. However, full-text search engines need to have a lot of features that classic databases have, in order to be able to search by specific fields, sort results, have proper scalability etc.

I saw people having a classic database, and additionally maintain e.g. Elasticsearch. I was reading a lot about all of the features full-text search engines need to have, it's really overlapping with features of classic databases. So, my question is: **do we even need classic databases alongside full-text search engines? Do databases have some additional features that full-text search engines don't? Can we just keep all of our data in a single full-text search database like Elasticsearch?**

Comment: Did you ever find some data on this?